# flask_socketio is hanging using any message_queue as SocketIO argument

Tags: flask, flask-socketio

Given the following example, well it's a quite simple example according to the documentation. I've got an error using redis or any other provider as a message_queue. Browser just hangs, although, if I just set message_queue to None (uncomment the line). Everything works as expected. Also, I do have kombu, redis and eventlet package pip installed on the enviroment. Using flask-socketio==4.2.1

```
from flask import Flask, jsonify
from flask_socketio import SocketIO, emit


message_queue = "redis://127.0.0.1:6379"
# message_queue = None


app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = 'secret!'
socketio = SocketIO(app,
                    async_mode='eventlet',
                    message_queue=message_queue,
                    manage_session=False,
                    logger=True,
                    engineio_logger=True)


@app.route('/')
def home():
    return """
        <html>
        <body>
        <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/socket.io/2.2.0/socket.io.js" integrity="sha256-yr4fRk/GU1ehYJPAs8P4JlTgu0Hdsp4ZKrx8bDEDC3I=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
        var socket = io();
        socket.on('connect', function() {
            socket.emit('my event', {data: 'Im connected!'});
        });

        socket.on('my response', function(data) {
            console.log(data);
        });
        </script>
        ok
        </body>
        </html>
    """

@socketio.on('my event')
def test_message(message):
    emit('my response', {'data': 'got it!'})
```

That's what is logged:

```
Server initialized for eventlet.
 * Restarting with fsevents reloader
Server initialized for eventlet.
 * Debugger is active!
 * Debugger PIN: 609-071-851
(70237) wsgi starting up on http://127.0.0.1:5000
(70237) accepted ('127.0.0.1', 53303)
39982ab1b7f84dee8e8d34dee1141cec: Sending packet OPEN data {'sid': '39982ab1b7f84dee8e8d34dee1141cec', 'upgrades': ['websocket'], 'pingTimeout': 60000, 'pingInterval': 25000}
```

using rabbit-mq i've got thouse logs from rabbit:

```
rabbit_1         | 2020-02-18 20:47:16.535 [info] <0.18859.0> accepting AMQP connection <0.18859.0> (172.31.0.1:46412 -> 172.31.0.6:5672)
rabbit_1         | 2020-02-18 20:47:16.581 [info] <0.18859.0> connection <0.18859.0> (172.31.0.1:46412 -> 172.31.0.6:5672): user 'rabbitmq' authenticated and granted access to vhost '/'
```

=== updated

Patching eventlet in the beguining of the file, didn't changed the behavior.

```
import eventlet
eventlet.monkey_patch()
```

The entire example script is stated. If you manage to make it run properly, please make a comment. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

My guess is that this is due to now having the standard library monkey patched to be compatible with eventlet. Add the following two lines at the two of your script:

```py
import eventlet
eventlet.monkey_patch()

from flask import Flask, jsonify
from flask_socketio import SocketIO, emit


message_queue = "redis://127.0.0.1:6379"
# message_queue = None

# ...
```

For more information on monkey patching, see https://eventlet.net/doc/patching.html.

I've also needed to add the `run()` call at the bottom, you omitted that in your listing:

```py
socketio.run(app)
```

With those two changes, I can run the Python script and nothing hangs for me. I suspect you may have been using `flask run` to run the server, but that is not the way to start the eventlet server, that only works for the Flask dev server. You have to use `socketio.run(app)` to start the eventlet server properly.

Comment: Thanks for answering Miguel, alghough. Even after the eventlet patch. I still got the same error. Patching didn't cause any effect. Did you manage to run the code?

Comment: Thanks miguel. It worked. Problem is not on the script it self. I had a module, with the script and a _._main_._.py file that does the socketio.run(app). The eventlet patch must be done there, and that was the problem. Thanks and congrats for the project.